# error: The Web server is configured to not list the contents of this directory

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis, iis-7

I've deployed my ASP.NET MVC web-app into IIS 7. And when I try to access to the web-app I'm getting the following error:

```
The Web server is configured to not list the contents of this directory.
```

How do I fix this to access to the web-app's pages. I'm not trying to let the end-user browse web-app's directories.

Any brilliant idea, please?

Answer (score 0):

You may try this.

Open iis -> select the web app -> goto features view -> select Directory Browsing -> Enable it